# Jquery Index Returns -1 when searching for 0

Tags: jquery

Why does jQuery index return -1 for a 0 in an array?

```
var myArray = [0,4,8];
document.write('<br/>8 is at index : ' + $(myArray).index(8));
document.write('<br/>4 is at index : ' + $(myArray).index(4));
document.write('<br/>0 is at index : ' + $(myArray).index(0));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JohnNeed/WGPMa/1/

Comment: You are using jQuery needlessly.

Comment: quick look in API docs would show that `index()` is not for javascript arrays  http://api.jquery.com/index/   . Wrapping an array in `$()` is highly uncommon since `$()` is typically used for the DOM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does jQuery index return `-1` for a `0` in an array?

Because you're using it incorrectly.  You're wrapping it with a jQuery object constructor.  jQuery expects its indexed slots to contain objects (reference to DOM elements), which are *truthy*. So when you pass in `0`, it's *falsy*, and fails the first condition (only *truthy* arguments are expected; jQuery was designed to handle no argument passed).

```
// No argument, return index in parent
if ( !elem ) {
    return ( this[ 0 ] && this[ 0 ].parentNode ) ? this.first().prevAll().length : -1;
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/traversing.js#L101)

If you change from `0` (falsy) to `5` (truthy), [it works as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgAZc/).

If you want to find the index of something in an array, use `indexOf()` on the plain array. If you *must* use jQuery, use [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) (this does have the advantage of working where `Array.prototype.indexOf()` doesn't exist).